# Can Visual Studio Task Runner raise an alert, or perform other Visual Studio automation?

Tags: visual-studio, task-runner-explorer

Can I use a Visual Studio "Task Runner Explorer" task to raise an alert or notification in Visual Studio?

I often find myself waiting for a Gulp build task to finish before refreshing my browser to see the results, but the little "background tasks running" icon in the bottom-left is a bit too subtle to distinguish at a glance. I'd like if my build could produce a more obvious alert, or even do some advanced automation - like trigger a refresh using Browser Link.